# How to calculate size of all gradle dependencies in android project

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies, size

I want to calculate size of all gradle dependencies separately, like want to get size of all third party libraries and all artifacts added in android project.

Comment: I think your are talking about analyze dependency

Comment: I am trying to get size of dependencies